# Bash script to clear files not matching a given extension

Tags: bash, cli

Using LaTeX creates a bunch of auxiliary files like `foo.aux`, `foo.log`, etc. Sometimes, I want to create a clean run of my document. I usually manually execute this in the terminal as

```
$ ls foo*
foo.tex
foo.aux
foo.log
foo.bbl
foo-blx.bib
$ rm foo{.aux,.log,.bbl,-blx.bib}
```

This works fine. However, it is error-prone and I don't want to accidentally erase my `.tex` file. So I added this function to my `~/.bashrc`:

```
# Delete all non-TeX files
# invoke as: cleantex foo
# where: foo.tex, foo.aux, foo.log, etc. are files in directory
cleantex () {
    if [ -n "$1"]; then
        name = $(basename -s ".tex" "$1")
        rm -f $name{.!(*tex),-blx.bib}
    fi  
}
```

My question is about the key line

```
rm -f $name{.!(*tex),-blx.bib}
```

that actually executes the script.

Is this line well-written? What might I improve here?

Comment: Which `basename` are you using? I am not familiar with (and can't find) the `-s` option for it.

Comment: I'm on Linux Mint 16 with GNU coreutils 8.20. My `man basename` has the option, as does the [official documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/basename-invocation.html#basename-invocation). Is your distribution out of date?

Comment: Essentially that fragment just trims the `.tex` suffix if there is one. So, `cleantex foo` is the same as `cleantex foo.tex`.

Comment: That option is not available on RHEL 6.4, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS ... which itself may be a problem. (I work in an 'enterprise'). Also, the basenames I have all will work that way without the -s option `basename foo.tex .tex` will produce `foo`. Food for thought

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My real concerns with the script are:

- `cleantex path/to/file.tex` will not delete files in that path, but in the current directory.
- you should check the actual .tex file exists before you delete all the things around it.
- the brace-expansion is unnecessarily complicated...... especially when combined with the extended glob `!(*tex)`. I would manually resolve the brace-expansion so that there is only one complicated operation on that line.
- I would use actual glob-expansion and only delete existing files.... and not use the -f option on rm (which does more than just suppress the error message if files do not exist....)

Answer (score 5):

Mostly minor things:

- `[ -n "$1" ]` is equivalent to `[ "$1" ]`. I'd go for the shorter one
- Since you are in `bash`, you can use a variable substitution `${1%.tex}` instead of `basename`, which is slightly better
- There cannot be spaces around the `=` sign in assignments: `name = val` is incorrect, should be `name=val`
- As @rolfl suggested in his answer, it would be better to check if a `tex` file exists before deleting anything

Putting it all together:

```
cleantex () {
    if [ "$1" ]; then
        name=${1%.tex}
        test -f $name.tex || return 1
        rm -f $name{.!(*tex),-blx.bib}
    fi  
}
```

Some extra remarks:

- I would add the `-v` flag for the `rm`, so that it will print what it actually removed: `rm -vf $name{.!(*tex),-blx.bib}`
- I guess you will never create `.tex` files with spaces in the name. If you ever do, you'll need to quote `$name`, for example: `rm -f "$name"{.!(*tex),-blx.bib}`
- I would drop the `-f` flag from `rm`. Sure, there will be some error messages that way when there's nothing to delete, but I don't see that as a bad thing.